# I enabled a Bitlocker pre-boot PIN and now I have to login twice, once for Bitlocker and once for Windows

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I'm running Windows 11 Pro on a new stand-alone PC. I want to secure my data while it is at rest, mainly as a defense against burglary and theft. I've configured Bitlocker to require a pre-boot alphanumeric PIN in addition to the TPM, and of course Secure Boot is enabled.

However, now I need to enter both my Bitlocker PIN and my Windows login password every time I boot up, which feels rather tedious. Is there any way to simplify the login process without sacrificing security?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147725/is-it-safe-to-enable-auto-login-in-windows-with-whole-drive-bitlocker-turned-on... dated, but might be what you're looking for.

Comment: (RE: auto-login to Windows): Thank you Haukinger, I have been looking into that. There are downsides, of course, but for a single user stand-alone system it might be ok. I'll try to learn more about it before making a decision.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you got exactly what you asked for.

Typically, TPM+bitlocker is considered good good enough for most people. It can be bypassed but, as far as I know and to this date, this requires specialized equipment.

Comment: To me, the idea that "logging in" to bitlocker replaces logging in to windows is not completely absurd. There's no reason that it would *not* work that way, in fact, at least in non-shared device scenarios.

Comment: @Haukinger "at least in non-shared device scenarios" -- you dismiss and discount this factor, but you shouldn't. The TPM PIN would become the sole means of ***identifying*** the user, which is then translated into an authentication for everything that relies on Windows account verification. Of course this isn't going to work. The PIN is to unlock the hardware. The ***operating system account login*** is for identity.

Comment: The TPM PIN obviously shouldn't be shared either, should it? In a perfect world, when creating a windows account or changing an account's password, the password would be updated for the associated pre-boot-account.

Comment: Stephane, Haukinger, schroeder, thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but here's what I've found:

The feature you are looking for is called Pre-Boot-Authentification or Single Sign On (SSO) for Bitlocker. There are several enterprise level solutions for this like Secure Disk for BitLocker or Kaspersky Endpoint Security. Just nothing for home or smaller volume usage.

However you could try a workaround. There is a feature called Autologin for Windows. I think it's called Autologon - I haven't tried it. Which lets you login into Windows directly after system boot. Good luck. I'd be interested whether it'd work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. After quite a bit of study and experimentation I decided that I wasn't comfortable with setting Windows to automatically login, even though the OS partition required a Bitlocker preboot PIN before it would decrypt, so I decided that the safest course of action was merely to continue entering the two sets of credentials every time I boot up. I've gotten used to it now and it's not so bad.